# Python : How to define and then also to be able to get and set textvariable in Labels in a loop

Tags: python, tkinter

I have tried to find a solution to the below problem, but the answers I found were not clear to me.

I have a loop from which I build my Frame widgets (each loop iteration builds a single row). In each row I define labels.

I would like to associate variables with their corresponding labels (and also later would like to be able to access label variables in order to change their value).

So the basic problem is to define variables in a simple way, eg. myvar_1, myvar_2, myvar_3.

To clarify: I want to set a variable in a loop as below:

```
  i=0
  for stockrow in sdb.db_get_account_stocks_data(self.account):
  **This is where I would like to define a variable**
    self.myvar_?  -> how to define that ??  = stringVar()
    lStock = ttk.Label(self,textvariable=self.myvar_?)
    i+=1 '''
```

So that later in a different method in my class where I calculate new values for myvar_*, I can control each of them because I know the row associated with which each myvar_? and subsequently assign a new value.

I would, for example, be able to do:

```
myvar_2 = 100
myvar_3 = 200
```

Thanks in advance.

Asaf

Comment: Why not use a dictionary or a list?

Comment: Read up on [Tutorial - 5. Data Structures](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#data-structures)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ought to consider something more like this:

```
i = 0
myvars_dict = {}
for stockrow in sdb.db_get_account_stocks_data(self.account):
    myvars_dict['myvar_' + str(i)] = stringVar()
    lStock = ttk.Label(self,textvariable=myvars_dict['myvar_' + str(i)])
    i+=1

myvars_dict['myvar_2'] = 100
myvars_dict['myvar_3'] = 200
```

Comment: Why could that be implemented only through out a dictionary ?

Comment: You could do it another way, but it would be much longer, much uglier and computationally more expensive.